# Typing on input field in an iframe causes the iframe to scroll to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, iframe

I have to display a full-screen modal containing an iframe with a form with input text fields. I already got the iframe to display and scroll correctly.

However, when I start typing on the input fields, the whole iframe scrolls all the way to the bottom, so you can't see what you're typing on the fields. It only scrolls when you start typing, not on focus.

This occurs on iOS Safari or Chrome and not on Android devices. Also note that the issue doesn't occur if I scroll to the bottom a bit, so that the input field is at around the vertical center of the screen (i.e. upper half of the screen), before tapping and typing on the field.

```html
<body>
  <!-- some contents -->
  <div class="wrapper">
    <iframe src="http://iframe.com" />
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
body {
  position: fixed; // I only set this to fixed via JS when modal pops-up
}

.wrapper {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Any help and pointers is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by setting the wrapper to `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`, and setting the following CSS to `html` and `body`.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Wrapper CSS now looks like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```